# Why can't I disable auto password generation in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, security

I can't turn off auto password generation,
I tried adding @SpringBootApplication(excludes = UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class) but then , when filling out the login and password , he writes :  No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
users and their roles are found in the database
my code

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    Securityhandler successHandler;
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
        return http.csrf((csrf)->csrf.disable()).authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {
                        authorize.anyRequest().authenticated();
                    }).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    
    }
    
}
```

```
    
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user=userRepository.getUserByUsername(username);
        if(user==null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user");
        }
        return new MyUserDetails(user);
    }

}
```

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails{
    
 private User user;
     
     public MyUserDetails(User user) {
           this.user = user;
        }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        
    Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
             
       for(Role role : roles) {
       authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
         }
             
            return authorities;
        }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return user.isEnabled();
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.se_nata</groupId>
    <artifactId>ATIRest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ATIRest</name>
    <description>ATIrest project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
           </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

```
 my  folder structure
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with you cannot turn it off? As soon as you register your own web security the auto configuration will back off.

Comment: @M. Deinum maybe I don't understand something, but how else do I need to register it?I did everything, tell me what else should I do? at the moment, the message still appears in the generated password

Comment: Which feels like your userdetails service and security config isn't in use. Else it will automatically backoff.Make sure that this config class is in a path that is covered by Spring Boot.

Comment: @M. Deinum Yes, it looks like it, but I can't figure out why

Comment: Without seeing your structure this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Also: I would avoid using snapshot versions of Spring Boot (you are using 3.2.0-SNAPSHOT) unless you want to test out some pre-release feature of a future Spring Boot version. Things might not work 100% in snapshot versions.

Comment: @M. Deinum I added all the classes to @ComponentScan(basePackages ={"ru.se_nata.ATIRest.security","ru.se_nata.ATIRest.entity","ru.se_nata.ATIRest.repository","ru.se_nata.ATIRest.service","ru.se_nata.ATIRest.restcontroller","ru.se_nata.ATIRest.modelassembler"})

Comment: Don't... If you need to do that your structure is wrong. Place your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in `ru.se_nata` and remove the `@ComponentScan`. Component scan won't work for entities, Spring Data repositories etc.

Comment: @M. Deinum please take a look I added a folder structure to the post,I have everything in separate folders, what should I move and where?

Comment: Ditch the `@ComponentScan` that isn't needed, everything is already covered by the `AtiRESTApplication` and I'm assuming that has the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on it. Problem is your `security` package is wrongly named and not covered hence your configuration isn't picked up.

Comment: @M. Deinum yes there is an anatation SpringBootApplication

Comment: As stated your security package is named wrong. It is missing a `.` between `nata` and `ATIREst`. Which is probably also why there is a warning signal next to the package!.

Comment: @M. Deinum thank you so much, I struggled for two days, I couldn't understand what was the matter)))))